# Ruby call "super" from a block (i.e in context)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, superclass, super, ancestor

Suppose I have:

```
class A
  include B
  include C
end

module B
  def test_method
    puts "Executed second"
  end
end

module C
  def super_calling 
    proc { super }  
  end

  def test_method
    "Executed first"
    super_calling.call
  end
end
```

I expected to execute the block `proc { super }` in context of the function `C::test_method`, so that `B::test_method` would have been invoked, but I get an error that says something like: "super_calling has not superclass" or something like that (don't remember exactly).

Everything works fine (no wonder) if `C::test_method` is defined like this:

```
def test_method
  "Executed first"
   super
end
```

My question is - I'm asking too much from Ruby or there is something I don't understand?
Can someone shed light on it?

Comment: I think you might have to declare the modules first before including them in the class.

Comment: @boulder_ruby Well, they are. The modules I have are located in Rails lib folder and are in fact automatically preloaded. So, I believe there are no issues with that part. :)

Comment: Umm, I believe the `super` refers to the method it's referred in (`super_calling`), not the method it's invoked from (`test_method`).

Comment: I think the proc uses the context it was defined in, rather than where it is executed. For example, try `def get_proc;x=1;proc{puts x};end;x=5;get_proc.call` (make readable first), you might expect it to print `5` (= value of x defined right before invoking proc) but it prints `1` (= value of x defined when creating proc). I think it's similar to your situation.

Comment: @MladenJablanović, yes, seems so. But the question is - is it possible to "redefine" it?

Comment: Pretty sure it's not possible using `super`, for sure. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MladenJablanović Nothing really serious.  
Improving my experience with ruby metaprogramming. :)
Also, wanted to introduce a syntax sugar in my system (reminds the example I provided). 
But I had a feeling that "super" is very special keyword and I won't be able to do much about it. 
Anyway, thank you for your support!

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers' example is great. You can view `super` as just another local variable defined in `super_calling`. Even if captured and passed using block, and invoked elsewhere, it will still refer to the same local variable from `super_calling`.

Comment: @MladenJablanović Yes. Now I see. Great example that really explains it.
Case closed. 
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove whole `super_calling` and just use `super` from within the `C::test_method`.

It will call `B::test_method` at that point.

Comment: Em. If I understand things right - not really. 
If you include both modules in that order, 
ancestors chain would look like this: [A, C, B, Object].

And "super" in context of C::test_method is B::test_method. 
If I explictly define "super" in C::test_method, B::test_method is invoked as it should.

Comment: Your answer seems wrong. When defining C's `test_method` with the regular `super` call, calling `A.new.test_method` will in fact output "Executed first", "Executed second". Thus, the call from module C to super does invoke the one in B.

Comment: Yes, my bad, call chain works. Problem with code of the user he tries to super 'super_calling' method, not the 'test_method'